# Align bottom for a custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

Lets say that I have a custom RelativeLayout which override onMeasure :

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
}
```

Now I'd like to add to this Layout a View which align with the bottom of this Custom RelativeLayout. But I tried different things without any results :

```
paramsButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
addView (mButton, paramsButton);
```

My first guess was to align bottom with parent (which should be the custom RelativeLayout right ?). But apparently, it aligns with the parent of my custom Layout (which is another RelativeLayout, not custom this time.

So I tried to align with id :

```
paramsButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, getId());
addView (mButton, paramsButton);
```

but it's not working either (the button disappears) 
NB : I set the id of my custom RelativeLayout explicitly to check that android did get the right id.

Do you have any idea how to make this work ?

**EDIT :**
Funny thing : It work well with the following rule

```
paramsButton.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
addView (mButton, paramsButton);
```

So I have to say that i really don't understand why the

> RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM

rule is not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach to overriding `onMeasure` is flawed. In this case, the layout measures its children (and they store their size) and then you tell just the layout (and not the children) that you actually changed your mind and would like to change that size.

Instead, try the following:

```
widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

In general, putting size in the code is not a great idea. Instead, consider using a style with fixed-size layout_width and layout_height or at the very least using `<dimen>` resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I'll try to make that work later in my day, and i report back to you !
Concerning the size in the code : It's just for the demonstration purpose ;)

Comment: it will work seriously....

I was close in finding that something is going wrong in overriding onMeasure but seriously had no idea what to do there...

@delyan  can you tell me some source from where i can have some knowledge regarding this..........

As this is completely alien to me, but your answer clearly shows that your are quiet clear with the facts

Comment: @AbhinavRathore, make sure you understand everything on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) page. After that, try reading and understanding the code for something simple like FrameLayout. Then, just play with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place another RelativeLayout/LinearLayout or any other layout/widget above the button and set its layout_weight to 1? By setting the layout_weight it will make the widget above the button take only the remaing space inside this custom RelativeLayout.

Comment: It could be a workaround but if I could understand the real issue it would be nice.